# JavaFx: Can not set javafx.scene.control.TableColumn field address.view.PersonOverviewController.firstNameColumn to javafx.scene.control.Label

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml, illegalargumentexception

Please help me to fix the below JavaFx exception. I got the below exception while i am working on JavaFx Tutorial from [code.makery.ch - JavaFX Tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/). I have attached ***PersonOverviewController.java*** and ***PersonOverview.fxml*** files. Update me if i need to provide any other details for fix this exception.

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
```

/F:/Ravi/Learning/Java%20Projects/AddressApp/bin/address/view/PersonOverview.fxml:55

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at address.MainApp.showPersonOverview(MainApp.java:88)
at address.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.TableColumn field address.view.PersonOverviewController.firstNameColumn to javafx.scene.control.Label
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 13 more
```

PersonOverviewController.java:

```
package address.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import address.MainApp;
import address.model.Person;

public class PersonOverviewController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> personTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;

    @FXML
    private Label firstNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label lastNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label streetLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label postalCodeLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label cityLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label birthdayLabel;

    // Reference to the main application.


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private MainApp mainApp;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
     */
    public PersonOverviewController() {
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Initialize the person table with the two columns.
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
    }

    /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     * 
     * @param mainApp
     */
    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        // Add observable list data to the table
        personTable.setItems(mainApp.getPersonData());
    }
}
```

PersonOverview.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="address.view.PersonOverviewController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="personTable" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="175.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" prefWidth="88.0" text="First Name" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameColumn" prefWidth="86.0" text="Last Name" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutY="6.0" text="Person Details" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" />
                  <GridPane layoutX="5.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="161.0" prefWidth="407.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="First Name" />
                        <Label text="Last Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="Street" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="City" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Label text="Postal Code" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                        <Label text="Birthday" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                        <Label fx:id="firstNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <Label fx:id="lastNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <ButtonBar layoutX="159.0" layoutY="244.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="160.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="147.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="253.0">
                    <buttons>
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="New..." />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit..." />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                    </buttons>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets right="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </ButtonBar>
               </children></AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you add some additional information what you tried so far.

Comment: At a glance it looks ok, but the exception suggests you had a `Label` with `fx:id="fisrtNameColumn"`. If you had this by mistake at some point and fixed it it may simply be that your compiler/IDE isn't aware of the change. Make sure all your files are saved and try to clean and re-build the project.

Comment: Thanks @sillyfly I had corrected the code but not clean the project. Now i had clean and re-build the project, its working fine. Thanks a lot.